# ByteBuddy AgentBuilder not working when running JUnit tests

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I created a java agent using ByteBuddy for method logging.

```
 return new AgentBuilder.Default()
            .type(ElementMatchers.nameStartsWith(targetPackageName))
            .transform((builder, typeDescription, classLoader, javaModule) -> {
                return builder
                        .visit(Advice.to(MyAdvice.class).on(ElementMatchers.isMethod()));
            });
```

`MyAdvice.class` have methods decorated with `@Advice.OnMethodEnter`. However, inside these methods, I reference a public static class with all its attributes and methods public static. I am able to log all methods using this approach when running the application, no problem.

However, there is a problem when I run a test class annotated with `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` For some reason, the instrumented code seems to disappear. Has anyone else experienced a similar issue?

For reference, I did a `-verbose:class` when running the test class in IntelliJ and the following classes are loaded just before the test class is:

```
    [Loaded org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1 from file:/Users/cberruz/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar]
[Loaded org.junit.runners.model.TestClass from file:/Users/cberruz/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar]
[Loaded org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkField from file:/Users/cberruz/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar]
[Loaded org.junit.runners.model.TestClass$FieldComparator from file:/Users/cberruz/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar]
[Loaded org.junit.runners.model.TestClass$MethodComparator from file:/Users/cberruz/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar]
[Loaded java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]
```

Update #1:
After adding `.with(Listener.StreamWriting.toSystemOut())` to my agent. The agent is able to DISCOVER a class, but right after I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.<init>(Unknown Source)
at net.bytebuddy.pool.TypePool$Default$TypeExtractor.<init>(TypePool.java:7672)
at net.bytebuddy.pool.TypePool$Default.parse(TypePool.java:680)
at net.bytebuddy.pool.TypePool$Default.doDescribe(TypePool.java:665)
at net.bytebuddy.pool.TypePool$Default$WithLazyResolution.access$001(TypePool.java:745)
at net.bytebuddy.pool.TypePool$Default$WithLazyResolution.doResolve(TypePool.java:843)
at net.bytebuddy.pool.TypePool$Default$WithLazyResolution$LazyTypeDescription.delegate(TypePool.java:912)
at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$AbstractBase$OfSimpleType$WithDelegation.getModifiers(TypeDescription.java:8331)
at net.bytebuddy.matcher.ModifierMatcher.matches(ModifierMatcher.java:48)
at net.bytebuddy.matcher.ModifierMatcher.matches(ModifierMatcher.java:27)
at net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatcher$Junction$Disjunction.matches(ElementMatcher.java:160)
at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$RawMatcher$ForElementMatchers.matches(AgentBuilder.java:1299)
at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$RawMatcher$Disjunction.matches(AgentBuilder.java:1191)
at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$ExecutingTransformer.doTransform(AgentBuilder.java:10302)
at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$ExecutingTransformer.transform(AgentBuilder.java:10263)
at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$ExecutingTransformer.access$1600(AgentBuilder.java:10029)
at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$ExecutingTransformer$LegacyVmDispatcher.run(AgentBuilder.java:10648)
at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$ExecutingTransformer$LegacyVmDispatcher.run(AgentBuilder.java:10595)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$ExecutingTransformer.transform(AgentBuilder.java:10186)
at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:428)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:459)
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:336)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:492)
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93)
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91)
at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116)
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:480)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:337)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.createProxyClassAndInstance(ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.java:54)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:201)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:109)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:463)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:346)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:421)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1634)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:756)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:128)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:281)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:249)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring typically does some class path scanning what might trigger loading classes before the agent is attached. Since you have not specified `.with(RetransformationStrategy.RETRANSFORM)` in your agent builder, Byte Buddy makes no attempt to redefine such classes and the transformation might get lost.

You can use `.with(Listener.StreamWriting.toSystemOut())` if you wanted to debug this, to see what classes are picked up by Byte Buddy.

Comment: Thank you for the help raphw! Can you please see my update on my original post? What exactly is causing the problem?

Comment: I assume you are using an old version with a very new JDK. Try updating, ASM does not seem to recognize your class file version.

Comment: I am currently using ByteBuddy 1.10.11. I have configured the maven-compiler-plugin to compile source and target to be Java 8. Do you have any idea on what else can I update?

Comment: I finally solved my problem. The tests run on a virtual machine, where I had my program packaged. However, when packaging my program an asm 5.0.3 dependency got packaged as well as an indirect dependency. This created conflict with the tests as they run on that VM